# How to declare conversions between different types of a templated class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a templated geometric vector class. Here is a simplified version of it.

```
template<class T>
class Vec3 {

public:
    Vec3(const T& x, const T& y, const T& z) {
        m_v[0] = x;
        m_v[1] = y;
        m_v[2] = z;
    }

    T m_v[3];
};
```

I use a double version of this class and a float version.

```
using Vec3D = Vec3<double>;
using Vec3F = Vec3<float>;
```

I would like to add is an implicit conversion from the float version to double version. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You might add template constructor (Possibly with SFINAE):

```
template<class T>
class Vec3 {

public:
    Vec3(const T& x, const T& y, const T& z) {
        m_v[0] = x;
        m_v[1] = y;
        m_v[2] = z;
    }

    // It is not a copy constructor.
    template <typename U>
    Vec3(const Vec3<U>& rhs) {
        m_v[0] = rhs.m_m_v[0];
        m_v[1] = rhs.m_m_v[1];
        m_v[2] = rhs.m_m_v[2];
    }

    T m_v[3];
};
```

If you want to handle only float to double, in C++20, you might use `requires` to "discard" method:

```
template<class T>
class Vec3 {

public:
    Vec3(const T& x, const T& y, const T& z) {
        m_v[0] = x;
        m_v[1] = y;
        m_v[2] = z;
    }

    Vec3(const Vec3<float>& rhs) requires (std::is_same_v<double, T>) {
        m_v[0] = rhs.m_m_v[0];
        m_v[1] = rhs.m_m_v[1];
        m_v[2] = rhs.m_m_v[2];
    }

    T m_v[3];
};
```

Comment: Pre-C++20 the SFINAE way would be to declare `template<typename = std::enable_if<std::is_same<double, T>::value>> Vec3(const Vec3<float> &rhs);`

Comment: @n314159: By SFINAE, I first thing about `is_convertible` or similar. And your version should be `template <typename U = T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<double, U>::value, int> = 0> Vec3(const Vec3<float> &rhs);` to be dependant of template of the function.